# Refresh error loading local storage data

Tags: javascript, dom, for-loop, local-storage

Sorry for being such a noob. I'm a student and I can't figure out what is wrong with my script. My code is a budget app where you enter values and it stores the info into local storage. It works when you calculate the expected and actual expenses, but when I refresh the page it adds a new row and with "undefined values". Any ideas?

```
<html>
    <body onload="load()">
        <div id="budget-list">

        <ul>
            <li>Expense Name</li>
            <li>Expected Amount</li>
            <li>Actual Amount</li>
        </ul>
        <div id="rowContent"></div>
        <div id="output">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Totals">
            <input type="text" id="output-expected">
            <input type="text" id="output-actual">
        </div>
        <button onclick="addRow()">Add New Row</button>
        <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="save()" />
        <input type="button" value="Add Expected" onclick="addExpectedTotals()" />
        <input type="button" value="Add Actual" onclick="addActualTotals()" />
    </div><!-- budget-list -->
 </body>
</html>
<script>


     /* BUDGET APP

******** 1. add a new set of rows
******** 2. enter data into input
******** 3. save data to local storage
******** 4. load data from local storage inside respective input id's
******** 5. calculate the total costs of expected/actual columns
    */

//a new line of rows
function addRow(){

    var rowNumber = getCurrentCount();
    var html = "<div class='rowClass'><input id='name-"+rowNumber+"' type='text'><input id='expected-"+rowNumber+"' type='text'><input id='actual-"+rowNumber+"' type='text'></div>";

    var currentHtml = document.getElementById('rowContent').innerHTML;        
    document.getElementById('rowContent').innerHTML = currentHtml + html;

}


// count the number of divs under rowContent
function getCurrentCount(){
    var parent = document.getElementById('rowContent');        
    return parent.getElementsByTagName('div').length;
}

// add the expected column totals
function addExpectedTotals(){

    var rowNumber = getCurrentCount();
    var all = new Array();

    // loop for expected 
    for(i = 0; i < rowNumber; i++){

        var expectedCol = document.getElementById("expected-" + [i]).value;
        var theArray = all[i] = expectedCol;  
        var total = (eval(all.join(' + ')));        

        var stringTotal = JSON.stringify(total);
        localStorage.setItem("ExpectedTotal", stringTotal);
        localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(stringTotal));
        var parseTotal = JSON.parse(stringTotal);

        var ouput = document.getElementById('output-expected').value = parseTotal; 


    } 

}
// add the actual column totals
function addActualTotals(){

    var rowNumber = getCurrentCount();
    var actualArray = new Array();

    // loop for actuals
    for(i = 0; i < rowNumber; i++){

        var actualCol = document.getElementById("actual-" + [i]).value;
        var createArray = actualArray[i] = actualCol;
        var addActual = (eval(actualArray.join(' + ')));

        var stringActualTotal = JSON.stringify(addActual);
        localStorage.setItem("ActualTotal", stringActualTotal);
        localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(stringActualTotal));
        var parseActualTotal = JSON.parse(stringActualTotal);

        var actualOutput = document.getElementById('output-actual').value = parseActualTotal; 
    }
}


// save the data
function save(){

    var rowNumber = getCurrentCount();

    // get the dynamic id for #name
    for(var i = 0; i < rowNumber; i++){
        var keyName = i;            
        var inputName = document.getElementById("name-" + [i]).value;
        var inputExpected = document.getElementById("expected-" + [i]).value;
        var inputActual = document.getElementById("actual-" + [i]).value;

        var allIds = [inputName, inputExpected, inputActual];
        var key_json = JSON.stringify(allIds);
        localStorage.setItem("Item-" + i, key_json);
    }

}

//load the data 
function load(){

    // add a new row for the data that is loaded
    for(i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
        addRow();

    }
    // loop through the input fields and parse the data
    for(i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){

        var row = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));
        var parsed = JSON.parse(row);

        document.getElementById("name-" + i).value = parsed[0];
        document.getElementById("expected-" + i).value = parsed[1];
        document.getElementById("actual-" + i).value = parsed[2];

    }
}


// initialize the app with a set of rows
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    addRow();
});
```

Comment: I think it has something to do with my for-loop and creating an array. It creates an empty value at the very end of the array in my addExpectedTotals() and addActualTotals(); I think that is throwing it off, but I don't know how I can remove that last item in an array if it's an empty value.

Comment: Possibly Its because your domcontentloaded thing creates an extra row? Try removing that

Comment: Also, could you get a working js fiddle? Is hard to debug it otherwise

Comment: Here's my JS Fiddle link. It doesn't seem to catch the local storage info.https://jsfiddle.net/udb67tyo/embedded/result/ But here is a link to the app online (sorry for the long url) https://dc79bd4fc6533540597ab0d2750f82dc67466245.googledrive.com/host/0B2uw8HdFLt_9VXF2MkVUR2x4UjQ/